# Getting a NullPointException, not sure why - Attempting to scan a file and write a String array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Not sure why this is getting a **NullPointerException**.

According to error log, NullPointerException is thrown while executing this statement. 
"file[i] = loadSaveFile.nextLine()" towards the end of the script.

```
public class SaveGame {
static String[] file;
static String loadSaveFile;
static String gameDir;
static int numLines = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File saveFile = new File(gameDir + "\\savefile.txt");
    Scanner loadSaveFile = new Scanner(saveFile);
    Scanner findNumLines = new Scanner(saveFile);
    while(findNumLines.hasNext() != false){
        findNumLines.nextLine();
        numLines++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        file[i] = loadSaveFile.nextLine();
        if(loadSaveFile.hasNextLine() == false){
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At no point are you setting the value of the array `SaveGame.file` itself, so it is defaulting to `null`.  You need to do something like

```
file = new String[numLines];
```

between the `while` loop and the `for` loop.

Comment: Woah I don't quite understand why but it worked. Thanks! Gonna spend a few minutes trying to learn what I did wrong, though.